# HTML.TextAreaFor I need to add the date/time stamp to the new comments being added in the field

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I have a `TextAreaFor()` that I need to add a date/time stamp to the end of what my users are typing. Any help would be appreciated.

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Comments, new { @class = "form-control", rows = 20})
```

Comment: Are you submitting a form? would you like the date/time stamp to appear there constantly with real time update or at the moment the form is posted? what are your data models?

Comment: The field in question is a varchar I just want to append it to the end of the comments in the form.

Answer (score 1):

This is better handled server-side on post. Simplistically, before you save:

```
model.Comments += Environment.NewLine + DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToString("o");
```

However, if you can, the superior approach would be to record the datetime in a separate column. Then, if you want it to appear with the display of the comment, you can, but you have properly normalized data.

Comment: This is correct, but an additional reason for the column would be to make sorting comments simpler, rather than having to do it via string parsing. (I know you know this.)

Comment: Well, I wasn't explicit, but that falls under having "properly normalized data".

Answer (score 0):

what I ended up doing was this in the post back of the controller.  I added the username as well.

```
model.Comments += $"- {DateTime.Now} - {User.Identity.Name}";
```